# JQuery Function to sort list alphabetically in <div> is not working, tried various variations

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I have been trying to sort this list within a div alphabetically, but either the list disappears, or nothing changes. Any tips please? Been struggling with this for days. Any tips would be much appreciated.

Edit: I have added the full Partial View to the Code Snippet.

Thanks.

```js
//Sort
var alphabeticallyOrderedDivs = $('.list-group-item').sort(function(a, b) {
  return String.prototype.localeCompare.call($(a).data('sortLis').toLowerCase(), $(b).data('sortList').toLowerCase());
});

var container = $("#assignedMemberList");
container.detach().empty().append(alphabeticallyOrderedDivs);
$('body').append(container);


function clearSelectedItem() {
  $.each($('#assignedMemberList .list-group-item'), function(idx, item) {
    if ($(item).hasClass('active')) {
      $(item).removeClass('active');
    }
  });
}
```

```html
 <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"  id="divClinicalManagementAssignMemberPanel">
        <div class="panel panel-primary" id="assignMemberPanel">
            <div class="panel-heading clickable ui-sortable-handle" style="text-align: center">
                ASSIGNED PATIENTS (<span id="assignMemberCount">0</span>)
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body assign-member-panel-body" id="assignMemberPanelBody">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Search" id="assignedMemberTxt" class="form-control" />
                        <div id="listAssignPatientContainer" class="overflowAuto well well-sm" style="height: 300px">
                            <div id="assignedMemberList" class="list-group">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12" id="listOfPageContent">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the usual `Array::sort`, you can easily implement your own jQuery plugin function `jQuery.fn.sort`:

```js
// map elements to any values you want
const mapped = Array.from($('div')).map(elem => ({elem, text: $(elem).text()}));
// sort the mapped array
mapped.sort((a, b) => a.text.localeCompare(b.text));
// sort the elements
mapped.forEach(({elem}) => $('body').append(elem));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Water</div>
<div>Lime</div>
<div>Banana</div>
<div>Melon</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. Unfortunately, it is still not working, even after I edited a few things and did some experiments. I am very inexperienced at JS.

Comment: @PLC8 could you provide a complete HTML that should be sorted? otherwise it's hard to help you

Comment: I have updated the View/HTML in the OP. It is a Partial View. Thank you.